# Azure function timer trigger not properly executing on CRON expression

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

I am using azure timer trigger function for triggering every 15 minutes in a day. So I set the time in TimerTrigger->Integrate->Schedule as 0 */15 * * * *. But the function is executing on every 5 minutes.

[image]

Is any problem in given CRON expression?

Comment: `0 */15 * * * *` is correct and I see function executes every 15m. Might be a silly suggestion but have you clicked `Save` after modifying the schedule?

Comment: yes, saved changes.

Comment: Looks like the function is consuming the old code(template is 5m). Just in case, have you tried the steps like refreshing(button next to functionapp), restarting or deleting and recreating?

Comment: You mean after updating the Shedule time, then restart the function, right?

Comment: Yes. But function runtime is supposed to reload the file changes automatically without any manual steps. Not sure what goes wrong on your side.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is wrong.

Try these

`0 */15 * ? * * // every 15 minutes starting at minute :00, of every hour`

```
* 0/15 0 ? * *  //every 15 minutes starting at minute :00
```

You can test it in [cron generator](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)

Comment: You can check them in the link on the post cron generator.

Comment: I edited my answer you can test them in https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: That cron generator link you provided, only allows for 7 characters, when I run that in Azure it throws an error, the default is 5 characters when you create a new timertrigger.  So I'm confused on proper format of these exprssions.  I've seen examples with 4 and some with 6, what is correct?

Comment: @AndyH cron expression isn't azure only.